# $f$ is measurable, $B$ is a Borel set $\rightarrow f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that $f$ is measurable and $B$ is a Borel set $\rightarrow$ $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

Hint: $\{A:f^{-1}(A) \in \mathbb{M}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets. (Here $\mathbb{M}$ is the set of all measurable sets)

So $B$ is a Borel set, which means it is a set formed from countable unions, intersections and relative complements of open sets.

I'm a bit lost here, the definition of a measurable function that I'm trying to use is that $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable for any open set $U$. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: See my edit for proper MathJax usage. In expressions like $$ \{ A:f^{-1}\in\mathbb M\}, $$ the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ should not be excluded from within MathJax. $\qquad$

Comment: Did you verify that the class of sets defined in the hint is a sigma algebra? Once you do that simply use the definition of the Borel sigma algebra as the smallest sigma algebra containing all open sets.

Comment: I'm a bit slow... How does this lead me to conclude that the inverse image of a borel set is measurable?